# How to create a common child class to be based on two separate base classes

Tags: javascript

What I have right now is two classes which each have a child class, but those child classes actually have the same extended functions in them. And I was wondering if there was a way to prevent code duplication through a more loosely tied class.

The reason why I need to extend the parent is because I want to be able to access the parent's methods within the child class.

Code below.

```
class Base1 {
    /**
     * @param {() => cy} getWrapper
     */
    constructor( getWrapper ) {
        this._getWrapper = getWrapper;
    }

    getSomething () {
        return this.getWrapper().find('something');
    }
    getWrapper () {
        return this._getWrapper();
    }
}
class Base2 {
    /**
     * @param {() => cy} getWrapper
     */
    constructor( getWrapper ) {
        this._getWrapper = getWrapper;
    }

    getHeading () {
        return this.getWrapper().find('heading');
    }
    getWrapper () {
        return this._getWrapper();
    }
}

class ReWrapBase1 extends Base1 {
    eq ( index ) {
        return new Base1( () => this.getWrapper().eq( index ) );
    }
    getWrapper () {
        return this._getWrapper().find( '[class*=SummaryItemstyles__Wrapper]' );
    }
}
class ReWrapBase2 extends Base2 {
    eq ( index ) {
        return new Base2( () => this.getWrapper().eq( index ) );
    }
    getWrapper () {
        return this._getWrapper().find( '[class*=SummaryItemstyles__Wrapper]' );
    }
}
```

My initial idea was to have the constructor hold the class, but then I realized I couldn't actually the parent's methods, which defeats the purpose.

```
class ReWrapAny {
    constructor(returnedClass) {
        this._returnedClass = returnedClass
    }
    eq ( index ) {
        return new this._returnedClass( () => this.getWrapper().eq( index ) );
    }
    getWrapper () {
        return this._getWrapper().find( '[class*=SummaryItemstyles__Wrapper]' );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to overwrite `getWrapper` method in the child classes? I don't understand which part of you code misbehaves with your objective. Could you please explain more. Provide some I/O please.

Comment: @Weilory No, it's that `ReWrapBase2` and `ReWrapBase2` both implement the same methods i.e. `eq` and `getWrapper`. However, they're different in that they extend different parent classes, because they need to be able to call different their respective methods. I was wondering if there was a way to put the `eq` and `getWrapper` methods into a class or something to prevent code duplication

Comment: so you want a bundle of function as mix-ins which passes into class inheritance? I am not sure if I got you correctly, but check [this](https://javascript.info/mixins) out

Comment: @Weilory Mixin might be it. I'll try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this to use a mixin.

```
function createMixin (baseClass) {
    eq ( index ) {
        return new baseClass( () => this.getWrapper().eq( index ) );
    }
    getWrapper () {
        return this._getWrapper().find( '[class*=SummaryItemstyles__Wrapper]' );
    }
}
export class ExportBase extends Base1 {}
Object.assign(AmountCards.prototype, createClass(Base1))
```